# How can i limit the angle of roation of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to limit the range of rotation of a div in between say 90deg to -90deg. the div should not go beyond the range we are defining. Consider this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aniprasanth/Cc6cr/1/. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your jsfiddle, you already now what the degree value is, so you could just check if the rotation falls within the range you've defined before changing the CSS transorm property:

```
if(degree < 90 && degree > -90) {
    // css transform changes
}
```

This will only apply the rotation between -90deg and 90deg.